# Show/hide jQuery optgroups of second multiselect based on the first multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using this jquery plugin http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

I have 2 multiselects. Each multiselect has two optgroups. The optgroups of second multiselect are dependent on the optgroup of the first multiselect. For instance, if all options of **optgroup1** of **multiselect1** are **unchecked**, then I will need to hide the **optgroup1** (including all options of optgroup1) of **multiselect2**.

I only know hiding and showing ALL the options of second multiselect when user click "Uncheck All" and "Check All" of first multiselect respectively using the following code.

```
             $("#ddlFirst").multiselect({
                height: "200px",
                noneSelectedText: "None",
                 checkAll:function() {
                     var second = $("#ddlSecond").multiselect();

                    // Show all the options of second multiselect
                    second.multiselect('widget')
                    .find(':checkbox')
                    .each(function() {
                         $(this).show();
                    });

                    second.multiselect('widget')
                    .find('li')
                    .each(function() {
                        $(this).show();
                    });
                    },
                    uncheckAll: function() {
                        var second = $("#ddlSecond").multiselect();
                        // Hide the all options of second multiselect
                        second.multiselect('widget')
                        .find(':checkbox')
                        .each(function() {
                           $(this).hide();
                        });
                        second.multiselect('widget')
                            .find('li')
                            .each(function() {
                                $(this).hide();
                            });



                    },
                click:function(event, ui){
                    //
                },
                optgrouptoggle: function() {
                    //
                }
            });
```

Now, I am trying to do the same at optgroup level. I am looking for solution for the following cases:

1. When user click on the optgroup label (let's say optgroup1) of first multiselect for checking\unchecking the options of this optgroup, then I will need to hide options of corresponding optgroup (optgroup1) of second(another) multiselect.
2. User may uncheck all options under the optgroup1 by manually clicking on each options one by one, then I will need to hide all options of optgroup1 of second multiselect.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code you've so far...

Comment: I have updated the question with my code.

Comment: And the HTML..? There is a nice feature called [stack snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/2333214) using which you can re-create what you've so far, which the users can easily fork into their answer... I'm feeling lazy today :)

Comment: The HTML is quite simple  <select id="ddlMultiselect1" multiple="multiple">
                        </select> <select id="ddlMultiselect2" multiple="multiple">
                        </select>
The data for these multiselects are pulled using ajax.